# jquery ajax won't work after it's been called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following jquery won't work as it was called by another set of ajax.  The radio buttons show, but upon selected, it won't open up the URL calendar.html.  However, if I tried to open this file without having it called by another set of ajax, it works perfectly fine and the URL calendar.html opens up beautifully.

Can someone help? I've heard of bind and live but don't know enough to incorporate it successfully. Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.button').click(function() {
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    var buttonSelected = this.id.replace(valueSelected + '_','');
    //alert('Button Selected: ' + buttonSelected + "\nValue Selected: " + valueSelected);
    $.ajax({

    url: 'calendar.html',           
        data:  '',
        cache: false,
    async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#ajaxDiv').html(result);


        },
        error: function (response, desc, exception) {
            // custom error
        }
    });

});
```

});

Comment: what do you see in the firebug console ?

Comment: So funnily, nothing shows up in the firebug console....I've also tried checking this on google's and ie's versions of firebug consoles and found nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters you don't need the data attribute, it is empty by default.

There aren't any errors that are popping right out at me, but you should make sure that you have the right path to calendar.html (be sure it is relative to the .html document that the JavaScript is loaded into).

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the path to calendar.html is correct. And, as mentioned above, this file (let's call this radio.html) works fine if I open up on its own. The problem is, this radio.html is preceded by another file which "Get" this radio.html via another set of ajax codes.   That's when it doesn't work...